# totalSupply doesn't pass test

Tags: solidity, blockchain, truffle-test

I'm starting programming. I wanted to do my first contract and I assigned totalSupply to 1000000.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;

/**
 * The DappToken
  contract Constructor
  Set the total number of tokens
  Read the total number of tokens
 */

  contract DappToken {

    uint256 public totalSupply; 

    function Supply () public {
    totalSupply = 1000000;  
    }
}
```

When I run test it doesn't pass. It says actual totalSupply is set to zero. Here is the code:

```
var DappToken = artifacts.require ("DappToken");

contract("DappToken", function(accounts) {
    var tokenInstance;

    it("sets the total supply upon deployment", function() {
        return DappToken.deployed().then(function(instance) {
            tokenInstance = instance; 
            return tokenInstance.totalSupply();
        })  .then(function(totalSupply) {
                assert.equal(totalSupply.toNumber(), 1000000, "sets the total supply to 1000000")
        });
    });
})
```

The result when I run truffle migrate is

```
Contract:DappToken
1) sets the total supply upon deployment 
> No events were emitted
```

and doesn't pass saying 
expected 1000000
actual 0

Comment: You haven't called function `Supply()`, what did you expect???

Comment: From the comment in the code, I think there's some confusion about constructors. I'd suggest changing `function Supply()` for `constructor()`.

Comment: @RichardHorrocks: That was my initial thought, but I immediately noticed that the contract's name was `DappToken`, so there's a little more than "constructor-confusion" here (also since this dude could have simply initialized that variable at declaration). I believe that he/she wants to test the value after it has been set, in which case, an explicit function (and an explicit function-call) is required.

Comment: @goodvibration - Yeah, good point - that argument probably makes more sense. Either way, the value is never set :-)

Answer (score 1):

Currently your code has a single public state variable totalSupply.  To set the value you need to execute the Supply function (as per the comments you received).

Recommend reading the OpenZeppelin guide on Tokens
https://docs.openzeppelin.org/v2.3.0/tokens